# Obtaining elevation data for each grid cell in raster image using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, elevation

I am obtaining a raster image from the internet for elevation data. There are two-three files available for a single location :

1. National Elevation Dataset 3 Meter, 1 map,
2. National Elevation Dataset 10 Meter, 1 map,
3. National Elevation Dataset 30 meter, 1 map.

What I want to do is for each raster image obtained, I want to make a grid of specific cell separation (preferably in terms of km/miles on actual raster image) and for each cell's (in grid) centre point obtain the latitude longitude information and associate it with mean elevation level of that grid cell. Ultimately I want a tabular format for coordinates along with their mean elevation value.

I am working on QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You currently have tags for QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop but do not tell us in your question body which one you wish to ask about.